# How to configure quorum queue in dapr pubsub for rabbitmq

Tags: dapr

I am try to write a pubsub component  for dapr and trying to use rabbitmq for queue functionality.
by default when application subscribes, it create a queue of type classic. my requirement is, i want to create queue type as quorum. please help on this.

Pubsub component

[image]

Subscription component:

[image]

dapr run --app-id TestApi --components-path LocalPath  --app-port 5074 dotnet run

Queue created in rabbitmq:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to define it in spec.metadata section

```
apiVersion: dapr.io/v2alpha1
kind: Subscription
metadata:
  name: pubsub
spec:
  topic: checkout
  routes: 
    default: /orders
  pubsubname: order-pub-sub
  metadata:
    queueType: quorum
```

https://docs.dapr.io/reference/components-reference/supported-pubsub/setup-rabbitmq/#use-quorum-queues